# Twilio click-to-call user can hear but not be heard

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I'm using Twilio click-to-call for conference calls.  There is a Chrome user in Portugal who was able to hear the call but couldn't speak.

His microphone works when I speak to him by Skype.  QiqoChat is apparently connected to his microphone, because he couldn't connect to Skype until he closed my app (apparently to release his mic).

How would you recommend I troubleshoot this?  It worked for 20 other users just fine but not this one.

Comment: You should consider asking this question at http://superuser.com/ instead. This questions seems off topic since its more about troubleshooting an IT issue rather than about development. Besides that, the many experts that search StackOverflow may not have the expertise in the area you need to help you.

Comment: Thank you @Dan for the note about superuser; I was not aware of it.  The Twilio staff are usually pretty responsive on StackOverflow.

Comment: Hey, I'm a developer evangelist from Twilio. I'd get in touch with help@twilio.com as they are more likely to help troubleshoot issues like this.